# Update & reload mysql using php - remove confirmation question

Tags: php

When I submit it asks to confirm, I have tried to remove the bit of code but wont work.

I want to submit and it updates with out been asked.

```
        $('body').on("change",'.guests_left',function(){
            var value = $(this).val();
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            var location = 'updateLeftGuests.php?sheet_id='+id+'&guests_left='+value;
            var txt;
            var r = confirm("This will change remaining guests, Are you sure?");

            if (r == true) {
                window.location.href = location;
            } else {
                location.reload();
            }

        });
    }
} );
</script>
```

Comment: So remove `var r = confirm("This will change remaining guests, Are you sure?");`

Comment: And fix the following IF accordingly

Answer (score 1):

use this instead:

```
$('body').on("change",'.guests_left',function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var location = 'updateLeftGuests.php?sheet_id='+id+'&guests_left='+value;
    var txt;
    window.location.href = location;
});
```

Comment: Glad to be of help! please accept my answer ;) (press on the check button next to my answer)